# SHA-1 SSL for my admin application showing as bad

Tags: visual-studio, security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to make an MVC admin application and I need to make this secure so I've just followed this tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/a/ to set the project up with SSL.

However, when I run the project in Chrome it's showing as non-secure (see below) because it's a SHA-1 signature (which I've since read is now considered dated which I guess is why Chrome now shows it as non-secure). My question is, how can I upgrade from SHA-1 to a SHA-2 function?

I've tried to do a bit of Googling but couldn't find anything particularly useful. My knowledge of SSL and secure applications is also fairly limited so please bear with me.

[image]

Certificate details:

[image]

Using VS2015.

Comment: did you start with a 1024 bit key or 2048?

Comment: I have no idea. Just followed the tutorial. How can I find out?

Comment: Actually I'm reading google is deprecating SHA1 as of 2016, you should use SHA256.  Are you using the latest Visual Studio?  I'd think that would work.

Comment: Yeah I am but when I ran the project (step 6 of that tutorial) all it says is that it's going to use SHA-1, no options for anything else. Now I'm not sure how to change it.

Comment: Does it show as invalid only in chrome? And could you paste a screen with "certificate information" as shown in your first screenshot? Maybe it's not in local machine trusted root store.

Comment: Yeah, just Chrome (and Firefox I assume from what the tutorial says haven't checked yet though). IE11 and Edge are fine. Screenshot of certificate info added above.